# What is the Postgres _text type?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a Postgres table with a `_text` type (note the underscore) and am unable to determine how to insert the string `[]` into that table.

Here is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.newtable (
    column1 _text NULL
);
```

I have the `postgis` extension enabled:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
```

And my python code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect()
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

rows = [("[]",)]
insert_query = f"INSERT INTO newtable (column1) values %s"
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, insert_query, rows, template=None, page_size=100)
```

This returns the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal: "[]"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO newtable (column1) values ('[]')
                                               ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

How can I insert this data? What does this error mean? And what is a `_text` type in Postgres?

Comment: It's seems that _text type does not exist. Try recreating your table with type text, or  run an alter table command to modify the data type.

Comment: AFAIK there is no `_text` type in Postgres or PostGIS. Did you create this table or was is created by some framework? The error suggests it is being seen as an `array` type and the value being supplied is wrong. See [Array input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) for correct format.

Comment: Alright some digging in the system catalog `pg_type` found it is a hidden 'alias' for a text array, `text[]`.

Comment: The `_` prefix is used to denote array types. The names can be retrieved through `pg_type` - if the column `typarray` is not zero, it points to the type entry that defines the corresponding array type: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6044018e890eeb387e3dbd14e07cb352

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pulling my comments together:

```
CREATE TABLE public.newtable (
    column1 _text NULL
);

--_text gets transformed into text[]

\d newtable 
              Table "public.newtable"
 Column  |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------+--------+-----------+----------+---------
 column1 | text[] |           |          | 

insert into newtable values ('{}');

select * from newtable ;
 column1 
---------
 {}
```

In Python:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into newtable values ('{}')")
con.commit()
cur.execute("select * from newtable")
cur.fetchone()
([],)
cur.execute("truncate newtable")
con.commit()
cur.execute("insert into newtable values (%s)", [[]])
con.commit()
cur.execute("select * from newtable")
cur.fetchone()                                                                                                                                                            
([],)
```

From the `psycopg2` docs [Type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) Postgres arrays are adapted to Python lists and vice versa.

**UPDATE**

Finding `_text` type in Postgres system catalog [pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html). In `psql`:

```
\x
Expanded display is on.

select * from pg_type where typname = '_text';
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+-----------------
oid            | 1009
typname        | _text
typnamespace   | 11
typowner       | 10
typlen         | -1
typbyval       | f
typtype        | b
typcategory    | A
typispreferred | f
typisdefined   | t
typdelim       | ,
typrelid       | 0
typelem        | 25
typarray       | 0
typinput       | array_in
typoutput      | array_out
typreceive     | array_recv
typsend        | array_send
typmodin       | -
typmodout      | -
typanalyze     | array_typanalyze
typalign       | i
typstorage     | x
typnotnull     | f
typbasetype    | 0
typtypmod      | -1
typndims       | 0
typcollation   | 100
typdefaultbin  | NULL
typdefault     | NULL
typacl         | NULL
```

Refer to the `pg_type` link above to get information on what the columns refer to. The `typcategory` of `A` as mapped in "Table 52.63. typcategory Codes Code   Category A  Array types" at the link is one clue. As well as `typinput`, `typoutput`, etc values.

Comment: This is helpful! Can you share where you discovered that `_text` is an alias for `text[]`?

Comment: Updated the answer with information about `pg_type` and `_text`.